# python facetgrid with sns.barplot and map; target no overlapping group bars

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn, facet-grid

I am currently implementing a code for facetgrid with subplots of barplots with two different groups ('type'), respectively. I am intending to get a plot, where the different groups are not stacked and not overlapping. I am using following code

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data,
            col='C',
            hue = 'type',
            sharex=False,
            sharey=False,
            size=7,
            palette=sns.color_palette(['red','green']),
            )
g = g.map(sns.barplot, 'A', 'B').add_legend()
```

The data is a pandas long format df with following example structure:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'A':['X','X','Y','Y','X','X','Y','Y'],
               'B':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
               'C':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
               'type':['ctrl','cond1','ctrl','cond1','ctrl','cond1','ctrl','cond1']}
                )
```

In the created barplots I get now fully overlapping barplots of the two groups, thus ctrlis missing, see below. However, I am intending to get neighbouring non-overlapping bars each. How to achieve that? My real code has some more bars per plot, where you can see overlapping colors (here fully covered)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to provide the `hue` argument to the barplot, not the FacetGrid. Because the grouping takes place within the (single) barplot, not on the facet's level.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data=pd.DataFrame({'A':['X','X','Y','Y','X','X','Y','Y'],
               'B':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
               'C':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
               'type':['ctrl','cond1','ctrl','cond1','ctrl','cond1','ctrl','cond1']})

g = sns.FacetGrid(data,
            col='C',
            sharex=False,
            sharey=False,
            height=4)
g = g.map(sns.barplot, 'A', 'B', "type", 
          hue_order=np.unique(data["type"]), 
          order=["X", "Y"], 
          palette=sns.color_palette(['red','green']))
g.add_legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I actually could implement factorplot wihich works compatible with barplots

Answer (score 9):

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52673435/1356000) shows up how to use FacetGrid directly.

But, if you have 0.9.0 installed, I would recommend you make use of [the new `catplot()` function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot) that will produce the right (at least I think?) plot. Note that this function returns a `FacetGrid` object. You can pass kwargs to the call to customize the resulting `FacetGrid`, or modify its properties afterwards.

```
g = sns.catplot(data=data, x='A', y='B', hue='type', col='C', kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. The hue of the facetgrid is correctly applied, i.e. it plots one barplot for each category in hue. The expectation to get a grouping *within* a single barplot would be satisfied by using the `hue` of the `barplot` instead.

Comment: You're probably right (as your answer clearly shows). I had tried to pass the hue parameter to barplot as well, bit I left it in the FacetGrid creation, and that didn't work either. In any case, I always find FacetGrid cumbersome to use. The new catplot is much easier to use.

Comment: `FacetGrid` is definitely not very transparent. I would suggest you remove the sentence about this being a bug, rendering this into a perfectly acceptable solution.